# Verifying asymptotic of sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

Let $p\in (0,1), q := 1-p$. Let $k_n$ be a sequence such that $k_n - np \sim c\sqrt{npq}$. I want to show that
$$\sqrt{\frac {n}{k_n (n-k_n)}} \sim \frac 1 {\sqrt{npq}}$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: If this is relate to probability, so add it's tag I think! One may use probabilities distributions to prove that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $\frac {k_n} n \to p$. Then write ${\sqrt {npq} \frac {\sqrt n}  {\sqrt { {k_n(n-k_n)}}}}$ as $\sqrt {pq} \frac  1 {a_n}$ where $a_n=\sqrt { \frac {k_n} n (1-\frac {k_n}n)}$. Can you now see that ${\sqrt {npq} \frac {\sqrt n}  {\sqrt { {k_n(n-k_n)}}}} \to 1$?

[$\frac {\sqrt {pq}} {\sqrt {p(1-p)}}=1$ because $q=1-p$].

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$A=\sqrt{\frac {n}{k_n (n-k_n)}}\implies A^2 =\frac {n}{k_n (n-k_n)}=\frac n { (c \sqrt{n p q}+n p)(n-np-c \sqrt{n p q })}$$ Now, let $n=\frac 1 {x^2}$ to make
$$A^2=-\frac{x^2}{\left(c x \sqrt{p q}+p-1\right) \left(c x \sqrt{p q}+p\right)}$$ Expand the denominator  to get
$${\left(c x \sqrt{p q}+p-1\right) \left(c x \sqrt{p q}+p\right)}=\left(p^2-p\right)+x \left(2 c p \sqrt{p q}-c \sqrt{p q}\right)+c^2 p q
   x^2$$ Now, long division to make
$$A^2=\frac{x^2}{p-p^2}+\frac{c (2 p-1)  \sqrt{p q}}{(p-1)^2 p^2}x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Factor the $x^2$ and continue with Taylor series to get
$$A=\frac x{\sqrt{{p-p^2}}} +\frac{c (1-2 p)  q }{2 (p-1)
   \sqrt{p q(p-p^2)}}x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Using $q=1-p$ and truncating, then replace $x$ by $\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ to get your result.

Comment: In my opinion, with $n = \frac 1 {x^2}$, one gets $A^2 = \frac{1}{(c\sqrt{pq} x + p)(1-p - c\sqrt{pq}x)}$

Comment: And the second equation for $A^2$ should be an $~$, but I am not even sure that this holds.